# How to blur in blender

Tags: animation, blur

First of all I am a beginner trying to make animations on my free time.

So now I want to make an that have to focus on a distant object first and blur the object that is closer how can do that. Any rendering engine would work.

Any help will be appreciated

(Blender version: 2.91.2)

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for Depth Of Field settings. Select your camera, and enter camera perspective (Numpad 0) to see what it's doing. The options are in the camera settings. You can even pick a focus object:

[image: DOF]

Comment: Thanks Christopher I didn't noticed your answer at first.

Answer (score 3):

You need to select your camera and in the *Properties panel > Object Data* > enable *Depth of Field*, then choose the object (or the empty) that will be the focus and play with the parameters:

[image]